# Allow user to run binary as root

Tags: linux, bash, security, permissions

I have a script written by someone else, which mounts a file system, and I would like to reproduce it.

The script has been compiled with shc, and is used to mount a filesystem for a particular user, but is able to be run with root priveleges. The guess is it does something like this `mount_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -t cifs -o username=$USER,domain=my_domain //hostname.com/Files /mnt/${USER}-drive
```

I have compiled the script with shc and then applied

`chmod u+s mount_script.sh.x`

so that

`-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root  root   11088 Feb 15 14:11 mount_script.sh.x`

matches the original compiled bash script's permissions, the original is wrapped with the following `mount_drive.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(mountpoint -q /mnt/${USER}-drive/ && echo "mounted" || echo "not mounted")" = "not mounted" ]; then
        echo
        echo "Not mounted, running mount script..."
        echo
        mount_script.sh.x
else
        echo
        echo "The drive is already mounted at /mnt/${USER}-drive..."
        echo
fi
```

WIth permissions:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 335 Sep 20 10:58 /usr/local/bin/mount_drive.sh`

When I try and run it as my normal user i get:

```
Not mounted, running mount script...

mount: only root can use "--options" option
```

1. What should the script contain to avoid this probelm and allow the $USER to run it successfully?
2. Is there any reason this would be a stupid idea from a security perspective?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of that you can add user option in /etc/fstab

Comment: or use `sudo`..

Comment: There are lots of users, and more can be added and I want them all to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is **NOT** intended for multiple users, then the simplest (*and most secure*) method is for the partition to be mounted via [fstab](/questions/tagged/fstab) with a specified user as owner of the partition and restricted privileges.  Namely,

```
UUID={something}    /   ext4    defaults,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0077,dmask=0077 0   1
```

That would have the partition mounted every time the system boots, but only the specified user could access that (or anyone with sudo privileges able to assume that identity).  If that leaves it too open, you could consider whether to encrypt that partition as well.  Implementing that is beyond my experience, but would allow only that user to mount/use/access on basis of the password required to mount. You also have to control the who and how the partition encryption password is changed.

If you pursue the encryption option, you can avoid the fstab approach, and allow the user to mount/unmount at will, since he would be the only one with the password.

The danger with encryption is that when the password is set, it needs to be stored securely, so that administrators can use to recover data when (not if) the organization loses the person that had the "master key".

Comment: Unfortunately it is intended to be run by multiple users.